# ASP.NET MVC code-first database to SQL Server Express login failure using Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, code-first

I am trying to generate a SQL Server database in SQL Server Express using   Entity Framework code-first.

I am getting a login error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException was unhandled by user code
>   Class=14
>   ErrorCode=-2146232060
>   HResult=-2146232060
>   LineNumber=65536
>   Message=Login failed for user 'ANDECOLAPTOP2\paultherrien'.
>   Number=18456
>   Procedure=""
>   Server=\.\pipe\0B36D920-CE4F-4E\tsql\query
>   Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
>   State=1

I am curious about this: "Server=\.\pipe\0B36D920-CE4F-4E\tsql\query", this does not appear to be a reference to my SQL Server.

Note: My login works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.  Also, when I use the SQL client in VS the SQL Server connects and I can run queries w/o issue.

This is what I have in my `web.config` for the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ISkillsContext" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\ISkillsDb.mdf;integrated security=true;user instance=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I am following a video tutorial and have emailed the author for help and have searched everywhere for ideas.

I am using VS 2015 Community Edition and SQL Server 2014 Express.

Thanks in advance.

Paul

Comment: This means that you connect to the database through the [named-pipe protocol](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189307(v=sql.105).aspx). You can enable/disable these protocols in the SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Comment: Thanks for that answer, but why would my login fail?  Because the pipe protocol is not enabled?

Comment: It appears that the database does not get generated.  Is there a setting or configuration option for code-first that I can set or check to ensure that the database is created?  I am using SQL Server Express 2014 and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Your connection string is a mixture of connecting to a server instance (`data source=.\SQLEXPRESS`) and localdb (`attachdbfilename...`). You should change the localdb part into a named database (`Initial Catalog`).

Comment: I appreciate your response, but this is what MS says to use:
    [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx) 

So I remain confused.

Comment: This is the sample i was going fron.
The following example is for a [SQL Server Express database in an .mdf file in the App_Data folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752.aspx).

Comment: I am at a real loss here....  the MS documentation specifically states how to set up the connection string and I set it up exactly as described.
    <add name="ISkillsContext"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\ISkillsDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
          />

Is there a log that gets generated that will show me more information as to why the MVC move-first logic is not working?

Comment: I ended up with this connection string:
      <add name="ISkillsContext"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
           connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\ProjectsV13;
           AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\ISkillsDb.mdf;
           Integrated Security=True;
           Initial Catalog=ISkillsDb;
           MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  Database=ISkillsDb"

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```xml
<add name="ISkillsContext"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\ProjectsV13;   
AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\ISkillsDb.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;
Initial Catalog=ISkillsDb;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True;  Database=ISkillsDb"
```